# Arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I am new into Python and i was trying to do an array like i was doing them on PHP but it seems that its different, so i look into online and it was talking about dicts and lupes i think was the other thing so i kinda figure out how to work the array with key and value but only for one entry. If i wanted to do multiple and have the input look at the array and post the information needed i was not able to do it.

The only think i need it to do its look for the state and apply the income tax amount. I was using this before i change it to what it is now. States = ['Name': "Alabama", 'Tax': "0.4"] then on the if statement i was calling the State['Name'] and ['Tax'] but that only worked for when i had 1 state and 1 tax. Hope this makes sense to someone else.

```
print('This software was create as a practice piece. This software will calculate income and break it down into different categories. It will deduct taxes based on the state you input. ')
    print('')
    print('Lets start with something easy!')
    print('')
    name = input('What its your name?')
    print('')
    print('Welcome', name, 'i will start by asking you a couple of questions.')
    print('')
    hourlyIncome = int(input('How much do you make an hour?'))
    print('')
    weeklyHours = int(input('How many hours do you normally work in a week?'))
    print('')
        # // Income math
    weeklyIncome = hourlyIncome * weeklyHours
    biweekly = weeklyIncome * 2
    monthly = biweekly * 2
    yearly = weeklyIncome * 52
        # Income math //
    print('- Got it!, So that is', weeklyIncome, 'every week')
    print('')
    print("- It's", biweekly, 'every two weeks.')
    print('')
    print('- This means that you make', monthly, 'a month since you get pay twice per month.')
    print('')
    print('- You make', yearly, 'a year.')
    print('')
    stateName = input('In what state are you located?')
    print('')
        # State
    States = [("Alabama",".05"),("Iowa","0.04")]
        # // States //
    if stateName==States["key"]:
        print(States["Name"],'has a', "{0:.0f}%".format(States["Tax"] * 100), 'income tax that is deduct from your income.')
        print('')
        # // Tax Math
        weeklyTax = weeklyIncome * States["Tax"]
        biweeklyTax = biweekly * States["Tax"]
        monthlyTax = monthly * States["Tax"]
        yearlyTax = yearly * States["Tax"]
        # Tax math //
        print('This is a ', weeklyTax, 'deduction in your weekly income making it', weeklyIncome - weeklyTax,'per week. Not just that if we calculate the remaining fields we are looking at', biweekly - biweeklyTax, 'every two weeks,', monthly - monthlyTax, 'monthly', yearly - yearlyTax, 'yearly.')
```

Comment: No, this makes little sense.  Do you have a question?  Does it fail?  Show the desired and expected output, and any error messages (full traceback) that occur.  See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, all those prints seems irrelevant. Can you trim those out?

Comment: The reason that i put them there was to create a blank line in between. Like i say i am new to python so i am just  making a simple script. Maybe it will make a bit more sense if you run it. here is the link https://repl.it/FIBl/150

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can safely assume you want to know how to create a dictionary, and how to iterate through it.

To create a dictionary:

```
States = {'Alabama': '.05', 'Iowa': '0.04'}
```

To loop through it:

```
for key in States:
  if key == stateName:
    #States[key] will return the value associated with the key, ex .05 for Alabama
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much, i will try to make a dict and see what happen but i think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

To use an array like in PHP with Python, you have to use dictionaries instead of a list. To use a dictionnary, it's `myDict = {'element1':12, 'element2':'banana'}` and to call an index, use `myDict[element1]`. 
To add a value to the end of your dictionary, like the `.append()` for the lists, use `myDict['element3'] = 'newElement !'` or to add multiple items at one time use `myDict.update({'element3':12, 'element4':'hi'})`.

Hope it helped you !

Comment: You should put backticks `\`` around inline code fragments. And since your dictionary keys are literal strings they should be quoted.

Comment: I did it, thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

i would do it like this but there is an error at the formating of the income. "{0:.0f}%" seams to be not correct.

```
print('This software was create as a practice piece. This software will calculate income and break it down into different categories. It will deduct taxes based on the state you input. ')
print('')
print('Lets start with something easy!')
print('')
name = input('What its your name?')
print('')
print('Welcome ' + name + ' i will start by asking you a couple of questions.')
print('')
hourlyIncome = int(input('How much do you make an hour?'))
print('')
weeklyHours = int(input('How many hours do you normally work in a week?'))
print('')
    # // Income math
weeklyIncome = hourlyIncome * weeklyHours
biweekly = weeklyIncome * 2
monthly = biweekly * 2
yearly = weeklyIncome * 52
    # Income math //
print('- Got it!, So that is ', weeklyIncome, ' every week')
print('')
print("- It's ", biweekly, ' every two weeks.')
print('')
print('- This means that you make ', monthly, ' a month since you get pay twice per month.')
print('')
print('- You make ', yearly, ' a year.')
print('')
stateName = input('In what state are you located?')
print('')
    # State
States = { "Alabama" : ".05", "Iowa": "0.04" }

    # // States //
if stateName in States:
    tax = States[stateName]
    print(stateName,' has a ', "{0:.0f}%".format(tax * 100), ' income tax that is deduct from your income.')
    print('')
    # // Tax Math
    weeklyTax = weeklyIncome * tax
    biweeklyTax = biweekly * tax
    monthlyTax = monthly * tax
    yearlyTax = yearly * tax
    # Tax math //
    print('This is a ', weeklyTax, ' deduction in your weekly income making it ', weeklyIncome - weeklyTax,' per week. Not just that if we calculate the remaining fields we are looking at ', biweekly - biweeklyTax, ' every two weeks, ', monthly - monthlyTax, ' monthly ', yearly - yearlyTax, ' yearly.')
```